# Should my resume list my bachelor's degree separately if my master's was in a different field?

Tags: career-development, education, masters

I plan on getting a master's degree in Computer Science after obtaining a bachelor's in Business Administration. Since these aren't related fields, **should I list both degrees separately on my resume**?

**What would be the advantages and disadvantages of following such a non-standard education for my profile as a job candidate?** Would employers frown on a candidate with a master's in CS but a bachelor's in an unrelated field?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question in a general way. Every company that values a CS masters degree has reasons. Every company that does not value a CS masters has reasons. It's impossible to know what they are without talking to each one.

Comment: If you had an undergrad in CS do you think an MBA would be frowned upon?

Comment: Both Joe and myself have provided answers to this question

Comment: A belated welcome to the site Squexis. I've made an aggressive edit to your post to hopefully make it on topic here and open it for more answers if it's reopened. If you disagree with my edits or they stray too far from your situation, please edit the question again to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do employers usually ask what was your bachelor degree if you have a
>   master in Computer science?

**Employers seldom ask**. But that's because you should put it on your resume, thus they won't have to ask - they can just read it.

You will indicate that your MS is in Computer Science. It would be extremely odd to indicate you have a BS or BA without indicating the field for this degree as well.

> since my bachelors is not in computer science or a related field would
>   the masters degree be frowned upon by the employers?

It might depend on the job you are seeking. But in my experience, if your MS in Computer Science is attractive to a hiring company, your bachelors degree will not matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are most companies will not dig too far past your recent work experience and highest qualification.

However, as a hiring manager, I actually value developers that have arrived in the field from outside computer science - my general experience (there are exceptions) has been that a pure computer science education produces a bit of a fish-bowl outlook to development and a bit of disconnect to how software actually needs to work in the real world. Then again, I'm not looking for algorithm or backend developers.

Depending on the kind of role you are going for and at what organisation, you might want to wave that bachelor's degree to show that you have some "real-world" education - particular as a large amount of software development is out there to provide business applications.

As always - you should be tailoring your resume and cover letter to each specific job application. Sure, this adds time and effort to every application - but I think you'll get a better response to the applications if you spend the extra 10-15 minutes to make sure you address the specific role you are applying for.

One additional thought after reviewing the question: if you only state a Master's degree in Computer Science on your resume, an employer might assume you took a 4 or 5 year direct course. This would be quite different to a 1 or 2 year post-grad course following a 3 or 4 year Bachelor's, so I'd be careful about possible misrepresentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should - they are two qualifications and also fill in the time line.

They also signify that you have multiple feathers in your cap. They can complement each other.